# Insert into table from CTE

Tags: mysql, insert, common-table-expression

I tried to insert data from `master_data` table into `tpl_transferred_debtor` table. Since `tpl_transferred_debtor` has primary key `tpl_code`, I need to use CTE to process data from
`master_data` before inserting.

```
with distinct_object_code_id as (
    select MIN(id) as id
    from master_data
    where original_type = 'tpl'
    group by object_code
), 
tmp_tpl_table as (
    select 
        md.accounting_id as accounting_id, 
        md.object_code as object_code,
        md.name as name,
        md.created_at as created_at,
        md.updated_at as updated_at
    from master_data md
    join distinct_object_code_id using(id)
)
insert into tpl_transferred_debtor (debtor_id, tpl_code, status, description, created_at, updated_at)
select 
    tmp.accounting_id, 
    tmp.object_code, 
    'active', 
    tmp.name, 
    tmp.created_at, 
    tmp.updated_at
from tmp_tpl_table tmp;
```

it give this error

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into tpl_transferred_debtor (debtor_id, tpl_code, status, description, cr' at line 17
```

I checked the CTE table `tmp_tpl_table` by remove the `insert into` line and it works fine.

```
with distinct_object_code_id as (
    select MIN(id) as id
    from master_data
    where original_type = 'tpl'
    group by object_code
), 
tmp_tpl_table as (
    select 
        md.accounting_id as accounting_id, 
        md.object_code as object_code,
        md.name as name,
        md.created_at as created_at,
        md.updated_at as updated_at
    from master_data md
    join distinct_object_code_id using(id)
)
select 
    tmp.accounting_id, 
    tmp.object_code, 
    'active', 
    tmp.name, 
    tmp.created_at, 
    tmp.updated_at
from tmp_tpl_table tmp;
```

If I don't use CTE to process the data, and just write a simple `insert into ... select`, then it works fine.

```
insert into tpl_transferred_debtor (debtor_id, tpl_code, status, description, created_at, updated_at)
select 
    tmp.accounting_id, 
    tmp.object_code, 
    'active', 
    tmp.name , 
    tmp.created_at, 
    tmp.updated_at
from master_data tmp
where tmp.original_type = 'tpl';
```

what did I do wrong here?

***EDIT***: The MYSQL database version is 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3.

Comment: What's your MySql version?

Comment: @Stu I edited to add the version.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), the right syntax would be `INSERT ... WITH ... SELECT ...`.

Comment: CTE is a part of SELECT query, not a part of INSERT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO tmp( tmp_id )
  WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS tmp_id FROM dual
  )
  SELECT tmp_id
  FROM cte;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are encountering a syntax issue related to the usage of the `CTE (Common Table Expression)` and the subsequent INSERT statement in MySQL.

In `MySQL`, you cannot directly use the `INSERT` statement immediately after a CTE definition. To overcome this, you need to encapsulate the `INSERT` statement within another `SELECT` statement. Here's how you can modify your query:

sql

```
WITH distinct_object_code_id AS (
    SELECT MIN(id) AS id
    FROM master_data
    WHERE original_type = 'tpl'
    GROUP BY object_code
), 
tmp_tpl_table AS (
    SELECT 
        md.accounting_id AS accounting_id, 
        md.object_code AS object_code,
        md.name AS name,
        md.created_at AS created_at,
        md.updated_at AS updated_at
    FROM master_data md
    JOIN distinct_object_code_id USING(id)
)
INSERT INTO tpl_transferred_debtor (debtor_id, tpl_code, status, description, created_at, updated_at)
SELECT 
    tmp.accounting_id, 
    tmp.object_code, 
    'active', 
    tmp.name, 
    tmp.created_at, 
    tmp.updated_at
FROM tmp_tpl_table tmp;
```

In this modified query, I wrapped the `INSERT` statement within an additional `SELECT` statement, which is a common workaround for this syntax limitation in `MySQL`.

This should resolve the syntax error you were facing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).